# Convert "Fri Apr 29 06:01:46 EDT 2016" to date format in HIVE?

Tags: date, datetime, hadoop, hive, type-conversion

I have a collected a bunch of tweets and loaded into Hive table. The time for each tweet is of the format "Fri Apr 29 06:01:46 EDT 2016". I would like to aggregate on only date i.e 04/29/2016.

Are there any functions that would help me get this format? Or should I do a substring to get year, month, date separately and collate them?

Any help is much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the built in date functions for this. Please find below the function usage for your case :

**from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Fri Apr 29 06:01:46 EDT 2016','EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy'),'MM/dd/yyyy')**

The code snippet:

```
select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('Fri Apr 29 06:01:46 EDT 2016','EEE MMM dd hh:mm:ss z yyyy'),'MM/dd/yyyy');
```

**UPDATE**

Refer [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions) for the hive builtin date time UDFs.

And [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html) for the timestamp formatting strings.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. Are there any references for these? I am kind of new to this.